# Form doesn't submit data to php

Tags: php, html, forms, macos

I set up a local server directory on my mac according to this: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083

I tried to make a simple test, following this: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_forms.htm
and process.php wouldn't display neither name or age, they are just void:

```
Your name is 
You are years old
In 25 years you will be 25 years old
```

What can be a problem with my setup?

P.S.
1. I have the same output with `http://localhost/process.php?Name=Bill&Age=35`
2. here is what i did to set up the form example:

```
[14:46:00]~/Sites/Tests$ cat > form2.html
<html>   
<head>
 <title>Test Page</title>
</head>   
<body>   
    <h2>Data Collection</h2><p>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">  
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Name"/></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Age:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Age"/></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>[14:52:32]~/Sites/Tests$ cat > process.php
<?php   
    print "Your name is ". $Name;   
    print "<br />";   
    print "You are ". $Age . " years old";   
    print "<br />";   $old = 25 + $Age;
    print "In 25 years you will be " . $old . " years old";
```

Comment: Are you using some template engine ?

Comment: @RoyalBg, I just did what was mentioned in these 2 articles. There was nothing about template engine. How to check it?

Comment: There's no mention of `{$REQUEST_URI}` and `{$LOGIN_USERNAME}` in that article. Where did you get that info from?

Comment: @klm123 the point here was that `<form action="{$REQUEST_URI}"` will not work as you never tell the interpreter that $REQUEST_URI is PHP variable. Template engines like Smarty uses tghis kind of syntax. But in plain `.php` file, this way won't work and variables will not be translated into php. Use `<?= $varName; ?>` instead

Comment: @RoyalBg Best to shy away from using open short tags and for so many reasons.

Comment: @RoyalBg, Fred-ii-, i see my question is too confusing... I simplified it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- shortened echo `<?=` is not bound to short_open_tags. It works without them being switched on from PHP 5.5. I guess this change is made to use them, instead of not.

Comment: Not when it comes to XML tags. @RoyalBg Those will be misinterpreted, just saying.

Comment: So now you've setup a webserver. Is PHP installed also?

Comment: @Fred-ii- if short_open_tags is `on` `<?xml` might be disinterpreted. But... if it's OFF and you have PHP 5.5, `<?xml` will be interpreted as you need, and `<?=` will not affect it

Comment: You have a point there. @RoyalBg

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes. I used php sripts with mysql DB successfully. And I run the sript, it prints the text.

Comment: @klm123 could you show us your PHP code from `process.php`

Comment: Actually, full source code.

Comment: in process.php, replace $Name with  $_REQUEST['Name'] and $Age with $_REQUEST['Age']

Comment: You're using a POST method, while you're using a GET method in the URL.

Comment: @klm123 super globals will not magically turn in to variables (unless register_globals is ON, but fortunately it is NOT). So you need to tell your script which superglobal array to take value from i.e. `$_GET['Age']`. Check `superglobals` in php's manual

Comment: @talkol, thanks. Now it works. COuld you kindly explain why?

Comment: I'll add a formal answer

Comment: @RoyalBg Make it an answer will +1

Comment: @klm123 also take a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php ... if you check the examples, you will see why your code is better TO NOT work :)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, talkol already answered :)

Comment: YOU were the one that should be getting the upvote here and YOU were the one who spent the time with the OP to resolve this, so YOU should be the one getting the credit. @RoyalBg I didn't see the other guy spending time but being on the sidelines. So put one in.

Comment: Never mind. @RoyalBg The important thing is the OP got a solution. I guess my coffee hasn't kicked in yet lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha :) I have added an answer, because of what you said, and because my opinion regarding $_REQUEST differs from talkol's :)

Comment: @RoyalBg I was just being a grump hahaha! I think you both deserve your answers to be accepted ;-)

Comment: lol, my answer in the comments came first ;)

Comment: Everyone's a winner here @talkol ;-)

Comment: Especially OP who has working code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long time ago, this was the common way that most of the PHP users thought that PHP works.

The parameters which were coming from the request were automatically registered as variables of the same name.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

This, as it can be seen from the article, appeared to be a bad decision and the team decided to deprecate and lately remove this feature.

So, request variables will not turn automatically into variables of the same name. You should specify where you expect the input to come from. POST, GET or COOKIE for example.

While, @talkol might be right that you can use `$_REQUEST` for both POST and GET, there is rarely good reason to do it.

In most cases, you need to expect them to come from the request method you do want the user to pass from. In your case, in the form its specified POST, so you only expect them as POST variables.

In order to access them, you need to use $_POST superglobal array. E.g. `$_POST['Name']`

All the information regarding superglobals you can find on the PHP officials documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: I actually prefer to use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST, because when debugging your code, you often use GET like OP did with `http://localhost/process.php?Name=Bill&Age=35`. And this way it still works :)

Comment: @talkol ofcourse it does:) but my opinion here differs. Using a certain method just because you will later debug is no good reason :) if you need to debug, you can debug with $_REQUEST into your debugging snippet, if you insist. But the other part of the script (the production one), should not be bind to the approach of debugging

Answer (score 3):

In process.php, replace `$Name` with `$_REQUEST['Name']` and `$Age` with `$_REQUEST['Age']`

The variables $Name and $Age aren't defined when your PHP script runs. You need to initialize them.

Parameters passed to PHP scripts are accessible via the [$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) super-global array. This array contains the value of every parameter using the parameter name as key. The common ways to pass parameters to scripts is via POST or GET. The $_REQUEST super-global works for both methods (unlike [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) which are similar super-global arrays, but they only work for one of them).

If you want to keep your original code, you can also initialize your variables using something like

```
$Name = $_REQUEST['Name'];
```

Be sure to place this line before $Name is used.

Comment: I will +1 because both you and Royal Bg helped the OP to resolve this.

Comment: I did +1 too. Wow we wrote that much on that topic, there will be no excuses for the others to ask the same question haha :)